# Parent chat user still links to discuss.area51 (instead of area51.meta)

Tags: bug, chat, area-51, chat-profile

When viewing a user who has their parent user on chat set to Area 51, it still links to discuss.area51.stackexchange.com, instead of the new URL, area51.meta.stackexchange.com. See:

[image]

[image]

So can we update these links?

Comment: Related: [Move all chat rooms hosted with discuss.Area51 to Area51.meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300476/335251)

Comment: An example that's still true: [see Jaydles' chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/19608/jaydles). The chat profile is parented to Area 51, and the link points to https://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/users/26/jaydles (which causes browsers to show a security error because there isn't a valid HTTPS certificate for `discuss.area51.stackexchange.com`).