# Move all chat rooms hosted with discuss.Area51 to Area51.meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, area-51

My previously posted bug is: [No chat rooms showing for Area51 (Change URL to add "discuss")](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293522/260388)

Which is still a problem: You'll never find a single room (even frozen or deleted) though the link of `chat` from top bar through area51.SE or area51.meta.SE because that links to `host=area51.stackexchange.com` whereas the existing rooms and newly-created rooms are linked to discuss.area51.stackexchange.com (which is now area51.meta.stackexchange.com).

My workaround in that mentioned bug was to manually change the URL to `host=discuss.area51.stackexchange.com` but as we know that https://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com is now moved to https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com, now

- Rooms that can be found out:

  > [image]
- and/or created:

  > [image]

will have their `host=area51.meta.stackexchange.com`.

Currently there are only two chat rooms hosted through area51.meta (one is frozen and second is I've just created to *verify* the host). All [other rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=discuss.area51.stackexchange.com) still have their `host=discuss.area51.stackexchange.com`.

So, **as discuss.area51 is now obsolete, I suggest to move all the rooms having `host=discuss.area51.stackexchange.com` to the newer `host=area51.meta.stackexchange.com`**

---

And Read my previously mentioned bug as: [No chat rooms showing for Area51 (Change URL to add <s>“discuss”</s> "meta")](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293522/260388).

---

<sup>Btw, What is [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65029/area-51) room not listed from any host ([area51](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=area51.stackexchange.com) or [area51.meta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=area51.meta.stackexchange.com) or [discuss.area51](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=discuss.area51.stackexchange.com))!? It seems created today and I can see some messages from feed bot.</sup>

Comment: looking at https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/19608/jaydles, the parent user is pointing to the wrong place. discuss.area51 has an expired certificate.

Comment: I think new rooms parented to Area 51 Discussions are associated with `area51.meta.stackexchange.com`... But older ones are still associated with `discuss.area51.stackexchange.com`, and simply trying to reparent them directly to "Area 51" again doesn't seem to fix it (it still uses the `discuss` link). I assume that reparenting them to another site and then back to Area 51 might fix it... (If it's even possible.)

Comment: Note: The same seems to be true of older chat rooms parented to `programmers.stackexchange.com` after the site's domain changed to `softwareengineering.stackexchange.com`. ([Rooms on the old domain](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&nohide=true&host=programmers.stackexchange.com) vs. [rooms on the new domain](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&nohide=true&host=programmers.stackexchange.com). There aren't any active rooms parented to their old domain anymore – though the mod room was until recently, which had been causing access issues.)

Comment: ...so this may be occurring for all older chat rooms parented to sites that have changed their primary domain.

Answer (score 6):

I re-parented the two remaining active Area 51 chatrooms that were still linked to `discuss.area51.stackexchange.com`. My best guess for the "ghost" room is that it was automatically created when the site's domain changed, which is expected when the system thinks we have a new site. I moved it over to the correct parent domain as well.